# How can I separate ID in ProximityIntentReceiver

Tags: android, location, proximity

My code send multiple location to ProximityIntentReceiver. Can I separate ID.
Example Send location A B C D. Location A B C  do other action when entering but when entering location D make notification.

private class GeocoderTask extends AsyncTask> {

```
    @Override
    protected List<Address> doInBackground(LatLng... locations) {
        // Creating an instance of Geocoder class
        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getContext());
        List<Address> addresses = null;
                try {
                    addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(locations[i].latitude, locations[i].longitude, 5);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

        return addresses;
    }

    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<Address> addresses) {

        //Log.i("Location","address = "+addresses);
        if (addresses == null || addresses.size() == 0) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "No Location found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        if (addresses != null) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Location found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            for (int i = 0; i < addresses.size(); i++) {

                Intent intent = new Intent("com.example.a57050358.testboat.util.proximityintentreceiver");


                Address address = addresses.get(i);
                latLng = new LatLng(address.getLatitude(), address.getLongitude());

                markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
                markerOptions.position(latLng);

                CircleOptions circleOptions = new CircleOptions();
                circleOptions.center(latLng);
                circleOptions.radius(Rd);

                PendingIntent proximityIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getContext(),i, intent, 0);

                locationManager.addProximityAlert(address.getLatitude(), address.getLongitude(), Rd,i, proximityIntent);

            }
            IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter ("com.example.a57050358.testboat.util.proximityintentreceiver");
            getContext().registerReceiver(new ProximityIntentReceiver(), filter);

        }
    }
}
```

class ProximityIntentReceiver

public class ProximityIntentReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

```
static int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1000 ;
int id = NOTIFICATION_ID;
boolean noti = false;

int short_gap = 200;    // Length of Gap Between dots/dashes
int long_gap = 1000;    // Length of Gap Between Words
long[] pattern = {
        0, long_gap, short_gap, long_gap, short_gap, long_gap
};
private Vibrator vibrate;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {


    String key = LocationManager.KEY_PROXIMITY_ENTERING;
    Boolean entering = intent.getBooleanExtra(key, false);
    String msg;
    if (entering) {
        Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "entering");
        msg = "Enter";
        noti = true;

    } else {
        Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "exiting");
        msg = "Exit";
        noti = true;
    }

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
    final Notification notification = createNotification();


    notification.contentIntent = pendingIntent;

         if (id == NOTIFICATION_ID) {
            //action change station
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context, 2);
            builder.setTitle("  Deaf Booster    ");
            builder.setMessage("          " + msg + "     ");
            builder.setIcon(R.drawable.icn3);
            builder.setCancelable(false);
            vibrate = (Vibrator) context.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
            vibrate.vibrate(pattern, 0);
            builder.setNegativeButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    vibrate.cancel();
                    notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;


                }
            });
            builder.show();
        }
        id = NOTIFICATION_ID++;
}




private Notification createNotification() {
    Notification notification = new Notification();
    notification.when = System.currentTimeMillis();
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_INSISTENT;
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS;
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
    notification.ledARGB = Color.WHITE;
    notification.ledOnMS = 1500;
    notification.ledOffMS = 1500;
    return notification;
}
```

}